# Application Insights bug when updating database

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights

I have recently installed application insights to my `ASP.Net MVC 5` project, and it works as intended.

But when I run `Update-Database` command to apply my migrations to database I get the following error: `Couldn't find type for class Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener`.

The project on which I run `Update-Database` is separate project ( class library ) which is included into web project.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

UPDATE: It works when I uninstall `ApplicationInsightsTraceListener` nuget package, but it would be good if it can be fixed without uninstalling it.

Comment: I just hit this as well

Answer (score 2):

When you run the migrations the entry point is the DbContext. It looks like you've not added the NuGet package for the ApplicationInsightsTraceListener to your Data Layer. Usually you only add the ApplicationInsights NuGet packages to the Web App and potentially your Console Applications/Web Jobs.

To get around this without installing the NuGet packages you can remove your Trace code from your DbContexts, also remember to remove them from the classes that your DbContexts relies upon. ..or just install the correct NuGet packages in the Data Layer too.

Regards..

Comment: Worked...I needed to add the package "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" to my data layer